# Skeleton visualization in Rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to visualize skeleton in Rviz. The skeleton tracking is done separately and skeleton data is subscribed by providing rostopic. Anyway, the skeleton can be considered as a combination of line strips, which is set of lines. Hence, I decomposed the skeleton into three LINE_STRIP as following:

1. `upper_body` # from head to spine base
2. `hands` # from left-hand tip to right-hand tip
3. `legs` # from left foot to right foot

I am adding points in these LINE_STRIP based on their location. The skeleton is moving. `upper_body.action = Marker.ADD` is keep on adding history points as well, which is not desired.

Below is the code snippet:

```
class SkeletonVisualization():
    def __init__(self):
        ns = 'skeleton_visualization'
        rate = rospy.get_param('~rate', None)
        body_topic = rospy.get_param('~body_topic')
        line_width = rospy.get_param('~line_width', None)
        fixed_frame = rospy.get_param('~fixed_frame', 'base')

        # define a subscriber to retrive tracked bodies
        rospy.Subscriber(body_topic, BodyArray, self.receive_bodies)
        body_pub = rospy.Publisher(ns, Marker, queue_size=10)

        # define the color of line strip
        green = ColorRGBA(0.12, 0.63, 0.42, 1.00)

        # from head to spine base
        self.upper_body  = Marker()
        self.upper_body.id  = 0
        self.upper_body.ns = ns
        self.upper_body.color = green
        self.upper_body.type = Marker.LINE_STRIP
        self.upper_body.scale.x = float(line_width)
        self.upper_body.header.frame_id = fixed_frame

        #from left hand tip to right hand tip
        self.hands  = Marker()
        self.hands.id  = 1
        self.hands.ns = ns
        self.hands.color = green
        self.hands.type = Marker.LINE_STRIP
        self.hands.scale.x = float(line_width)
        self.hands.header.frame_id = fixed_frame

        #from left foot to right foot
        self.legs  = Marker()
        self.legs.id  = 2
        self.legs.ns = ns
        self.legs.color = green
        self.legs.type = Marker.LINE_STRIP
        self.legs.scale.x = float(line_width)
        self.legs.header.frame_id = fixed_frame

        rate = rospy.Rate(rate)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            body_pub.publish(self.upper_body)
            body_pub.publish(self.hands)
            body_pub.publish(self.legs)
            rate.sleep()

    def receive_bodies(self, data):
        if not data.bodies:
            print('[WARN] No body found')
            return;

        body = data.bodies[0] # ignore other people
        time = rospy.Time.now()

        self.upper_body.header.stamp = time
        self.hands.header.stamp = time
        self.legs.header.stamp = time

        self.upper_body.action = Marker.DELETE
        self.hands.action = Marker.DELETE
        self.legs.action = Marker.DELETE

        self.upper_body.action = Marker.ADD
        self.hands.action = Marker.ADD
        self.legs.action = Marker.ADD

        for joint in body.jointPositions:
            if not joint.trackingState:
                return
            if joint.jointType == 3: #head
                self.upper_body.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 2: #neck
                self.upper_body.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 20: #spine shoulder
                self.upper_body.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 1: #spine mid
                self.upper_body.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 0: #spine base
                self.upper_body.points.append(joint.position)

            elif joint.jointType == 21: #hand tip left
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 7: #hand left
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 6: #wrist left
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 5: #elbow left
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 4: #shoulder left
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 20: #spine shoulder
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 8: #shoulder right
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 9: #elbow right
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 10: #wrist right
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 11: #hand right
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 23: #hand tip right
                self.hands.points.append(joint.position)

            elif joint.jointType == 15: #foot left
                self.legs.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 14: #ankle left
                self.legs.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 13: #knee left
                self.legs.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 12: #hip left
                self.legs.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 0: #spine base
                self.legs.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 16: #hip right
                self.legs.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 17: #knee right
                self.legs.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 18: #ankle right
                self.legs.points.append(joint.position)
            elif joint.jointType == 19: #foot right
                self.legs.points.append(joint.position)
```

Following are my questions:

1. How to delete skeleton points after each callback?
2. Is there any better way to visualize skeleton in RVIZ?
3. The `if-elif` is too long to read. Is there any better way to assign points to `Marker` keeping the real-time visualisation in mind?

I am using ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274509/skeleton-visualization-in-rviz/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is a perfectly fine way of visualizing a skeleton in RVIZ. I would recommend adding them all into one [MarkerArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/MarkerArray.html) message, I found it provides a much better refresh than sending individual markers.

As for simplifying your if statements, I think you could use an array to map the numbers to different objects for a slight speedup, but I find your code perfectly readable, you just have a lot of different body parts.

---

Originally posted by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) with karma: 136 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2017-10-30**:
Thank you very much. I learned something new, i.e., MarkerArray. I have a question. In the above code, I used `marker.action = Marker.ADD`, hence it keeps on displaying old lines as well. I want to delete old lines, hence I used `marker.action = Marker.DELETE` BUT it didn't work. Any comments?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-30**:
You can set some short `lifetime` as described [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html).

**Comment by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) on 2017-10-30**:
I seem to recall that making an array solved the whole redraw/update problem. I had originally tried to set a short `lifetime` on my many `Marker` messages as @l4ncelot suggested, but now I'm using a `MarkerArray` with `lifetime=1s` and it doesn't show any old lines despite updating at 10 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there any better way to visualize skeleton in RVIZ?

You could try the [skeleton_markers](http://wiki.ros.org/skeleton_markers) package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2017-10-30**:
I noticed that the package you provide also using the similar code. Thanks a lot.